# ¿Hay algún equivalente en español para "red herring"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, solicitud-de-modismo

En [una pregunta de Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010910/why-does-sizeofa-true-false-give-an-output-of-four-bytes%20de%20stackoverflow)  vi el uso de una expresión en inglés que me pareció muy interesante:

> The ternary operator is a red herring.

Siguiendo un enlace de Wikipedia para [Red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring) se puede encontrar una definición para dicha frase:

> A red herring is something that misleads or distracts from a relevant or important issue.

Con lo que entiendo de la explicación en el mismo sitio acerca del origen de la expresión, se refiere a un pez curado fuertemente oloroso con el que supuestamente se entrenaban sabuesos. La intención era entrenar al perro para que al fin fuera capaz de ignorar el fuerte olor del pescado y se concentrara en la presa real.

[Pons](https://en.pons.com/translate?q=red%20herring&l=enes&in=&lf=en) propone la traducción "pista falsa" para esta expresión. ¿Tenemos en español una manera figurativa o al menos no tan literal como "pista falsa" para la expresión en inglés "red herring"?

Comment: Para más sencillo, quizás: Es un a distracción [de la idea central -- o algo por el estilo].

Comment: "Pista falsa" parece la traducción más genérica. Por ejemplo, la novela "Five red herrings" de D. Sayers en español es "Cinco pistas falsas y lo mismo ocurre con "Twelve red herrings" de J Archer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En español tienes la expresión `cortina de humo` que es de acuerdo al [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=B2uMIwC) "Artificio de ocultación". Otras expresiones podrían ser `jugar al despiste` o `maniobra de distracción`.

si en lugar de un modismo buscas un término considera "falacia"

> [falacia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HVXQdUl)
>
> 1. f. Engaño, fraude o mentira con que se intenta dañar a alguien.

o su equivalente `señuelo`

> [señuelo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XcUbjzu)
>
> 4. m. Cosa que sirve para atraer, persuadir o inducir, con alguna falacia.

Usado en el ejemplo que pones, podrías decir

> El operador ternario es [falaz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HVzTBTi)

En cualquier caso una "red herring" lo que hace es *mislead* (confundir o engañar en español), por lo que para mi la mejor traducción habría sido

> El operador ternario  **lleva a engaño**

pero "lleva(r) a engaño" no es realmente un modismo (es una expresión muy literal).

Comment: Buena respuesta en cuanto a "cortina de humo". Con lo que no coincido es con _falacia_: me parece una palabra demasiado gruesa, en la que solamente un _engaño_ suave podría encajar. El operador ternario descrito en el código no es ni fraude ni mentira, solamente una manera de ofuscar el código o liar al personal.

Comment: @fedorqui de acuerdo que falacia es una palabra gruesa, pero a mi me suena del _mismo calibre_ que **red herring**. El ejemplo **el operador ternario es falaz** me suena perfecto.

Comment: @fedorqui Cierto (y edito). A mi "el operador ternario es falaz" me suena mejor que "el operador ternario es una _cortina de humo_". Supongo que puede depender de la intencionalidad. Posiblemente la mejor traducción sea la "pista falsa" que ya se incluyen en la pregunta.

Comment: Diego y @DGaleano ciertamente yo baso mi traducción en el contexto de la respuesta donde se usó, pero de buen seguro que el uso que le da Diego está más sustentado en la realidad que el mío :)

Comment: corina de humo es smokescreen

Answer (score 4):

[WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=red%20herring) señala otra posible traducción que me gusta bastante: ***maniobra distractiva***.

Observemos el caso: [la respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47012220/1983854) nos está diciendo que el código

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a ? true : false)); // Why 4?
```

es equivalente a:

```
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(true));
```

Por lo que el código `a ? true : false` es básicamente una forma de decir `true` de una forma un tanto compleja, como ***maniobra distractiva*** de lo que realmente es importante.

Comment: Buena traducción de _the ternary operator is a distraction_ pero no del mismo **grueso calibre** de _red herring=falaz_ jajaja.

Answer (score 1):

Otra alternativa, podría ser el término `misdirección`.

> *Misdirection* is a form of **deception** in which the **attention** of an audience is focused on one thing in order to **distract** its attention from another.
>
> Fuente: "[Misdirection (magic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misdirection_(magic))". Énfasis mío.

En la magia (magia de salón, trucos con naipes, etc.) la *misdirection* es por ejemplo cuando el mago te dice "no pierdas de vista esta carta", tú te fijas concienzudamente en la carta y mientras diriges toda tu atención a esa carta el mago hace otra cosa en otro sitio. Mientras tu atención está centrada en el sitio al que él la ha dirigido, y por tanto efectivamente distraída de lo que a él realmente le conviene, el mago aprovecha para que su juego de manos pase desapercibido.

En otras palabras, te dice "no pierdas de vista mi mano derecha" y mientras tú obedeces él realiza el juego de manos con la mano izquierda.

En el mundillo de la magia se emplea con frecuencia el anglicismo `misdirection`, pero hay quien emplea la españolización `misdicección` y el término "[diversión](http://dle.rae.es/?id=E0eav7y)" (en su tercera acepción "*Acción de distraer o desviar la atención y fuerzas del enemigo.*"), como se puede ver en [este hilo del foro magiapotagia](http://www.magiapotagia.com/showthread.php?t=3750).

> Conoceis algun buen libro sobre **misdireccion** (sic)?
>
> No me hagas mucho caso, pero en el libro de Ascanio puede que hable de *Misdirection* ya que es todo teoria magica, que alguien confirme....(sic)
>
> Tienes razón ExtrEm0, en el primer tomo de Ascanio tiene un capitulo dedicado a la **misdirección** . Yo estoy devorando ese libro estos días, y la verdad es que espectacular...
>
> [...] En esta diversidad de obras encontrarás consideraciones sobe la **misdirection** (**diversión**), el control de la atención, los puntos de interés, efecto tubo, etc.

Este término no está recogido en el DRAE y por supuesto, **implica intencionalidad**. Este término implica el control de la atención de la audiencia, por lo que decir que

> Hay una **misdirección** en el operador ternario

implica que alguien ha querido ocultarte algo a propósito. Aunque eso cuadra con algunas de las connotaciones de `red herring` admito que no es la traducción que yo favorecería. No obstante, quería aprovechar para dar a conocer el término, que me parece interesante.

Comment: "pero hay quien emplea la españolización misdicección" ¿Acá es misdirección?

Comment: @MauricioMartinez, depende de dónde es "acá". Creo recordar que detrás del foro de _Magiapotagia_ estaban magos **españoles** de reconocido prestigio (como Tamariz). Había una zona para iniciados y luego te tenías que ganar el derecho al acceso a otras zonas del foro donde se discutían cosas más "secretas" (es un foro para magos. No se revelaban los trucos así como así). En cualquier caso, presumo que "misdirección" es poco usado a ambos lados del charco, prefiriendo el anglicismo.  No hay término oficial. Los libros de magia la describirán como "misdirection", o "control/dirigir la atención".

Comment: bueno en realidad mi pregunta era si había un error en una letra de la palabra "misdicección". Pero igual muy interesante la explicación. Me recuerda a las sociedades secretas y sus grados de iniciación. Muy del tipo masonería jeje

Answer (score 1):

La palabra red herring para mi la relaciono con las historias/cuentos. En los libros o películas un red herring es cuando el que cuenta la historia deliberadamente te presenta algún aspecto como importante o lo que determinará el desenlace, y mientras tu mente está en eso, te sorprende con otro desenlace. Fuera de las historias, se usa el término de una manera más suelta. Por ejemplo, en el ámbito de la tecnología, obviamente el ternary operator se supone que sea fácil de entender, lógico, claro. Usar la palabra red herring para describirlo da a entender que es de alguna manera confuso o engañoso.

Answer (score 0):

Una respuesta tardía me ha traído hasta aquí.
Una vez leidas todas las respuestas y la referencia original en Stack Overflow, me parece que una palabra en castellano que refleja fielmente el concepto de **red herring** es

[**trampantojo**](https://dle.rae.es/trampantojo)

> De trampa ante ojo.
>
> 1. m. coloq. Trampa o ilusión con que se engaña a alguien haciéndole ver lo que no es.

Quiero hacer notar que NO es el operador ternario per se el que se califica como red herring sino esa expresión concreta que es innecesariamente compleja.

Me adhiero a la respuesta aportada por Diego, en ese caso la expresión incluida en el operador ternario puede **llevar a engaño**, con lo cual podemos decir simplemente que es una expresión **engañosa**.

**[engañoso, sa](https://dle.rae.es/enga%C3%B1oso?m=form)**

> 1. adj. Falaz, que engaña o da ocasión a engañarse.

Eso sí, yo no la calificaría de **falaz** porque normalmente se asocia la palabra falaz con su primera acepción, la cual no es aplicable en este caso (para más inri, una expresión booleana que acaba siendo igual a **true**).

**[falaz](https://dle.rae.es/falaz)**

> Del lat. fallax, -ācis.
>
> 1. adj. Embustero, falso.
> 2. adj. Que halaga y atrae con falsas apariencias.

Answer (score 0):

La mayoría de respuestas, irónicamente, están cayendo en un "red herring" propio.

"Red herring" (una frase hecha) implica un fallo de análisis. O sea, quien está mirando o investigando algo se distrae o confunde y persigue la línea de investigación/argumental incorrecta.

En historias de detectives o policíacas se usa mucho cuando se sigue una pista que parece tener sentido pero termina no teniendo relación directa.

Lo más importante es que un "red herring" no requiere ni implica malicia por parte de un segundo actor.

Las propuestas tipo "engaño", "falaz", "trampantojo", "misdirección", "diversión", "cortina de humo", "señuelo" son todas incorrectas en espíritu al original, porque todas requieren un actor malicioso (al menos en sus acepciones reconocibles por contexto al utilizarlo, donde "red herring" es unívoca).

"**Pista falsa**" es la mejor –aunque bastante ortopédica– opción hasta que el tiempo mismo cree una frase hecha igual de absurda ("red herring" significa "arenque rojo", de un artículo del S.XVIII, de uno contando como los arenques rojos se usaban para que por su olor se distrajesen los perros que perseguían a las liebres, usado como analogía de los medios evitando las noticias problemáticas reportando las llamativas) que pueda usarse unívocamente para el mismo significado.

Comment: No entiendo bien lo que indicas de traición al sentido original. Tanto en el significado que aparece en el diccionario Oxford https://www.lexico.com/definition/red_herring "A clue or piece of information which is or IS INTENDED to be misleading or distracting." (mayúsculas mías para resaltar) como en la historia que incluyes la pista falsa es intencionada, hay un actor malicioso.